# What does `1<<0` do in this code snippet?

Tags: assembly, nasm, bitwise-operators

What does these lines of code do ?

```
MBALIGN     equ  1<<0                   
MEMINFO     equ  1<<1
```

I know with `equ` we declare constants in nasm, but what does `1<<0` do?

It looks similar to C bit operators but as far as I know in assembly we use `shl` and etc.

Comment: In assembly you use [expressions to compute everything you possibly can at assemble time](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc3.html#section-3.5), not at runtime.  There is no compiler to optimize anything for you.  This is just a human-readable way to write the constants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the shift does nothing it makes things easier to read, think of

```
MBALIGN     equ  1<<0
MEMINFO     equ  1<<1
```

as saying

```
MBALIGN     equ  BIT0
MEMINFO     equ  BIT1
etc.
```

Comment: Thanks, it was really helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

`<<` is [a bit shift operator](http://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.12.01/html/nasmdoc3.html#section-3.5.4) and it is like what it is in C for unsigned integers. `1<<0` shifts `1` by 0 bits, so the result is 1.

> << gives a bit-shift to the left, just as it does in C. So 5<<3 evaluates to 5 times 8, or 40.

Using CPU instructions is required to do shift *in runtime* in assembly, but you can use expressions to be converted to a immediate value *in compile (assemble) time* if your assembler supports them.

Comment: but why would we use 1<<0 when it doesn't change anything?

Comment: If it really doesn't change anything, you can choose whether to use it freely. But I think it will change clearness of the meaning: `1<<0` is better than `1` to express "the first bit being 1".

Comment: @EhsanAkbari Seems you are over thinking things. The reason for the 0 shift is not functional but rather stylistic - to make it stylistic consistent with the other constant which has a non-zero shift.

Comment: @kaylum That's the real answer: it's there to express 1 in the same way the following line expresses 2, for the benefit of the reader, not the assembler

Comment: @kaylum : I think your comment is probably the best answer to the question I've seen so far.

Answer (score 1):

Those lines are defining constants. In this case, those are flags that can be bitwise or'd together and tested individually. It's easier to see the structure of flags by defining them as shifts of 1. You would get the same effect by writing out the value of that expression, but it would be harder to see which bits mean what.

(In this case, having bit 0 set means `MBALIGN` is set, and bit 1 means `MEMINFO`.)